# How to replace a function in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am writing some unit tests for a module that uses a scheduler. I'm writing a fake of the scheduler so that I can examine what events have been scheduled, cancelled, etc.

The code I'm testing calls the schedule function directly with the help of `using namespace X` calls, and the final call is `scheduler::schedule()`. So, I need to have my fake's function be the one called when that function call is made.

I can't change the library, and I think what I need to do here is override the function in the namespace, but I'm not exactly sure how I should do this. To top it off, the scheduler is implemented elsewhere and is imported to this code project with `using namespace` calls, and the library implementation has several different `using namespace X` calls in it at each level of namespace nesting "for backwards compatibility."

How should I go about doing this?

Basically, we have this:

```
namespace ndn {
namespace util {
namespace scheduler {

class Scheduler
{
  EventId
  schedule();
}

} // scheduler
} // util
} // ndn
```

And then in my local codebase:

```
namespace nfd {
namespace scheduler {

using ndn::Scheduler;

EventId
schedule();

} // scheduler
} // nfd
```

And now, the code I'm writing looks like:

```
namespace nfd {
namespace rib {

scheduler::schedule(...);

} // rib
} // nfd
```

So, what I need is that call to `scheduler::schedule()` to be for my fake. In my test case I have:

```
namespace nfd {
namespace rib {
namespace tests {

//test code

} // tests
} // rib

// Can I do this?
namespace scheduler {
  EventId
  fakeSchedule();
} // scheduler

} // nfd
```

Can I just inline another namespace call and overwrite the call there? If not, how should I fake the scheduler so that I can accomplish this?

Comment: It seems that namespaces in C++ are becoming what things like AbstractFactory are in Java - a way of completely obfuscating the code,

Comment: Unfortunately I have to agree. I think they are a useful tool, but the pull to just make another namespace is so strong, and then you end up here.

Comment: I don't find the pull strong at all. If I ever come across a case where I had more than one layer of namespaces, I would definitely think very, very hard about my design. I wrote a blog article about this a wile back: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/letter-the-sixth-belatedly/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You can't "override a function in a namespace".

You could write a fake scheduler with the *same* function, and link the module under test with the fake scheduler instead of the actual scheduler, when you build the unit tests.

Otherwise there is no way to do this in C++ without changing the code under test.

Comment: I thought this was the case, but I figured I should ask just in case I had missed something. Thank you for the quick reply.